# sklearn, can't import power_transform

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, anaconda

I am receiving the following error when trying to use power_transform in sklearn's preprocessing module. I am importing as follows:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import power_transform
```

The error I get is:
**ImportError: cannot import name 'power_transform'**

I can use other functions from preprocessing (like scale)
I installed sklearn 0.19.1 via anaconda. Any ideas what is going on here?

Comment: what version of scikit-learn do you have?

Comment: It is available in *scikit-learn v0.20.dev0* apparently. By default anaconda is currently using *scikit-learn v0.19.1*

Comment: Good question. Looks like I have a version that doesn't support this function

Comment: Thanks, add that as an answer if you like and I will mark it as correct, as this might help others. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**power_transform** is available in version *scikit-learn v0.20.dev0*. It is not available in *sklearn 0.19.1*

***Sources***

- [power_transform on sklearn documentation site for v0.20.dev0](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.power_transform.html)
- [power_transform is not present on documentation site for v0.19.1](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.preprocessing)